# How do I handle routing when on browser reloads in riotjs?

Tags: routes, riot.js

I've read through the [documentation](http://riotjs.com/api/route/) and while it handles routes which change as a result of the url (hash) changing, it doesn't explain how to handle routing for bookmarks/reloads.

I understand it's a minimal router, but surely it must be able to handle loading routes when the browser is refreshed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `riot.route.exec()` in your main tag/init method. It looks at the current hash and issues the corresponding routing: http://riotjs.com/api/route/#riot-route-exec.

Comment: I clearly wasn't paying enough attention.  I'll blame it on the information overload in first steps using this.  Thanks for your reply, appreciate it.